# Writing to a particular cell location using Apache POI Excel

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi

If I've got an list of parameters 'x,y,z' that aren't sorted, is there a straightforward way to write them to particular cells in an excel document created with POI, as though the first two parameters are X and Y coordinates?

For example, I have rows like:

```
10,4,100
```

Is it possible to write the value '100' in the cell at the 10th row, 4th column?

Looking at the documentation, it looks straightforward to iterate values into the next row, but I can't see any way of creating a fixed number of rows and columns and writing particular values to only certain cells.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, it's very easy, just remember that POI is 0 based not 1 based in addressing. Assuming you want to write to the 10th row, 4th column, you'd do something like

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(9); // 10-1
if (r == null) {
   // First cell in the row, create
   r = sheet.createRow(9);
}

Cell c = r.getCell(3); // 4-1
if (c == null) {
    // New cell
    c = r.createCell(3, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
}
c.setCellValue(100);
```