# Putting result of Java program into Excel cell

Tags: java, excel, apache

I simply want to put the result of a Java program into an Excel cell. Let's assume the result is `5`, then my code in main() would look like this:

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = C:\Users\Username\Desktop\java-programs\results.xlsm;
    XSSFSheet ExcelSheet = wb.getSheet("numbers");
    XSSFRow row = ExcelSheet.getRow(0);
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(5);
```

However, this code doesn't compile.

I read some examples on this topic but the code given simply refers to the Excel sheet as (e.g.) "sheet" and then goes on with `sheet.getRow(some number)`. The examples don't explain how I tell Java which workbook to write to.

Comment: What is the error message that you get on compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to a particular cell location using Apache POI Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112958/writing-to-a-particular-cell-location-using-apache-poi-excel)

Comment: it gives several error messages ... for example: "; expected" and "illegal character '\' "

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is incorrect.. try this:

```
 String fileName = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/java-programs/results.xlsm";
 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn);

 // update the workbook
 wb.getSheet("numbers").getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue(5);

 fileIn.close();

 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
 wb.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();
```

Comment: With  the code "XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-programs\\results.xlsm")));" at the beginning, it now compiles ... I can even run the program without getting an error message .... Alas, the number "5" is not printed into the excel sheet ... nothing is happening there

Comment: Did you write it out with a FileOutputStream?

Comment: if I use FileOutputStream, I get the following error message when running the file:  "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Comment: The code I added to the previous code was the following:
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-programs\\results.xlsm");
      wb.write(fileOut);
      fileOut.close();

Comment: fileIn.close(), then create fileOut.

Comment: now I'm getting error message at compilation: "cannot find symbol   variable fileIn"